# How can use my custom image as icon in leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, leaflet

in my asp.net core website. i want use 4 different icon for 4 different subject in leaflet map. i use the sample code, But my custom image not show on the map. how can solve this?
my JavaScript code is:

```js
const map = L.map('map').setView([35.598764, 51.436572], 13);

const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    minZoom: 5,
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var greenIcon = L.icon({

    iconUrl: '~/image/main/icon1.png',
    shadowUrl: '~/image/main/shadow1.png',
    
    iconSize: [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

var marker = L.marker([35.585978, 51.434942], { icon: greenIcon }).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.");
```

Comment: Your `iconUrl` contains the wrong url. If you try it with a url from the internet it works: ` iconUrl: 'https://bodylab.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/map-marker-icon.png'` --> [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JzxafSNV1VcbZ110)

Comment: i dont want using icon or image from internet. i want using my own pic.

Comment: Yeah I know but to test if your code works, you can use one from the internet and then you see you have problem with your image path and not with Leaflet code

Comment: i test it with your lino or any other icon from internet and worked. and the from the name of parameter (iconurl) I should use image from internet. So i can not  use my own asset for this? or have another way?